# Inserting VLOOKUP formula in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert a VLOOKUP formula in a cell. I am not even trying to substitute parameters yet. I use this code:

```
myCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "=VLOOKUP(A2;AnotherWorksheet!$A$1:$B$231;2;FALSE)"
```

And I am receiving an error: 1004

If I paste that exact formula in a cell, then the formula is recognized and accepted...
Any hint? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `,` and not `;` when separating the arguments. Second, you're looking for the `.Formula` property, not `.Value`. `.FormulaR1C1` may work, but for exactness, just use `A1`-style formula writing for your `VLOOKUP`. See below.

**Code:**

```
Sub Voom()
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A2,""AnotherWorksheet!$A$1:$B$231"",2,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

It shows `#N/A` because, of course, I have no data available. :)

For your exact code, just use:

```
myCell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,""AnotherWorksheet!$A$1:$B$231"",2,FALSE)"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Formula` property.

For example:

```
myCell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,""AnotherWorksheet!$A$1:$B$231"",2,FALSE)"
```

From MSDN, the [Formula property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb213521%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and the [FormulaR1C1 property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb213527%28v=office.12%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Should be `.Formula` only and not `.FormulaR1C1`. Either works, but for the sake of exactness... :)

Comment: @bk201 worth posting that as the answer :)

Comment: @brettdj: As you wish, my liege. Though I have to say, running `.FormulaR1C1` on this formula also works. I just had to change aphoria's `;` to `,`.